# Content of a table cell showing hexadecimal number wrongly interpreted

Tags: org-export

I have this table in org-mode that I wish to export to pdf:

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :align |r|r|r| :font \ttfamily \tiny 
|service | port |  hex   |
|--------|------|--------|
|mdns    | 5353 |  14e9  |
```

after export **14e9** in the pdf is replaced with **14(9)** in the table.

How do I get the right value in the export?

What component is doing this misinterpretation? Tabular is used for LaTeX table.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `org-latex-table-scientific-notation` is responsible for this behavior.

Customize this variable and set it to **No formatting** option to avoid conversion of numbers resembling scientific notation.

Alternatively, use upper-case for your hex values, which look nicer than lowercase.