# org mode to latex: weird export of "1.00E-10"

Tags: org-mode

I am writing a report in org-mode, and I have some tables with elements of the form "1.00E-10". When I export the document, these elements are converted in the Latex file as:

> `1.00\,(-10)`

How to prevent this behaviour ? I was not able to find any documentation on this.

Thanks !

Comment: Extremely related: [Content of a table cell showing hexadecimal number wrongly interpreted](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34481/content-of-a-table-cell-showing-hexadecimal-number-wrongly-interpreted).

Comment: Exactly ! This is the solution !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Content of a table cell showing hexadecimal number wrongly interpreted](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34481/content-of-a-table-cell-showing-hexadecimal-number-wrongly-interpreted)

Answer (score 2):

So it appears that the suggestion from Juancho, pointing to [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34481/content-of-a-table-cell-showing-hexadecimal-number-wrongly-interpreted) is the way to go. After doing `(setq org-latex-table-scientific-notation nil)` the export is now what I want.

Thanks again !